# Dereferecing in gsp inner html

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a layout file. I want something like this in each of my pages inheriting that layout:

```
Just ${step} Steps Away From The Awesome!!
```

So in my layout I have defined a string as above with a placeholder `step`. I dont want to pass the value of this placeholder from controller. I wish to define it in the gsp that inherits this layout.

I was looking for something like `<g:set var="step" value="1"/>` (or 2 or 3 depending on the gsp). But it does not work if I define it like that.So how do I dereference the value of "step" inside each extending layout?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to accomplish this is to make use of `content blocks` and `page properties`. These are both features derived from Sitemesh.

I assume you only want to conditionally include this information when the page using the layout provides a value. So in my example here I have wrapped it in a quick `if` check.

In your layout:

```
<g:if test="${pageProperty(name: 'page.step')}">
    Just <g:pageProperty name="page.step" /> Steps Away From The Awesome!!
</g:if>
```

Then in any page that uses the layout you can include the content for the variable step

```
<content tag="step">3</content>
```

Note that the value within the `content` tag can be whatever you like. It will be evaluated when the page is rendered.